# rewording "in doing (verb)"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I have a question about the meaning of these statements:

> 1a- The most effective ***method in developing*** and improving health
>   is considered to be daily exercises. (Original)
>
> 1b- The most effective ***method  developing*** and improving health
>   is considered to be daily exercises.
>
> 1c- The most effective ***method to develop*** and improve health is
>   considered to be daily exercises.

---

> 2a- He is ***wrong in saying***, "Jack is stupid" . (Original)
>
> 2b- He is ***wrong saying***, "Jack is stupid" .
>
> 2c- He is ***wrong to say***, "Jack is stupid" .

---

Can I use the other versions instead of the 1a and 2a? Do 2b and 2c mean the same thing as the 2a version, and likewise with 1b and 1c?

Comment: C versions sound fine to me. B ones, though, not so much

Comment: 1d- The most effective method ***of/for*** developing and... 2c- is my choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use "method for developing" or "method of developing". "Method to develop" is possible, but I don't find it as natural. The others I would not say.

"Wrong to say" is most natural for me, followed by "wrong in saying". I wouldn't say "wrong saying".

Note that questions like this are about the requirements of the particular words *method* and *wrong*: they are not governed by general rules.

Comment: Thank you. What does "in" mean in the a versions?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden: It's the same "in" as ***In** what way / **In** what respect?* as responses to the non-specific utterance ***He's wrong***. Just an (optional) preposition loosely identifying the relationship between the "basic" statement (that he is wrong), and the specific wrong thing that he did.